# Conditional code compilation of specific binary

Tags: rust, flags, conditional-compilation

Can we enable `--features` flag for a specific binary automatically? For example, to build `server` binary with `forserver` feature, we're not obliged to,

```
cargo build --features forserver --bin server
```

Instead, we only need to write in `Cargo.toml`,

```
[[bin]]
name = "server"
features = [ "forserver" ]
```

and straight to `cargo build --bin server`.

Or alternatively, is there `#![cfg(bin = "server")]` notation to enable compilation of a code block just for specific binary?

Comment: It would definitely work if you move server and other things into a different crate, which then sets different feature flags on a common library. I'm not sure whether it works for a shared crate too.

Comment: Shared crate for client and server then? Thanks, noted, in case this has no solution.. My program is just very small, one file each :(